# Airbag light is on after taking seats out

Tags: troubleshooting, suzuki, supplemental-restraint-system

I am looking for troubleshooting help on my 2011 Suzuki kizashi, I bought it recently and wanted to detail it, so I instinctively removed the seats and started cleaning. Unfortunately I was in aware I needed to disconnect the battery before hand. I am hoping it is a minor enough issue that I can fix it, or fix it for cheap. It is my first car and so I have no idea what to do. Anything helps!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! To my thinking, it could be one of two thing (or both). The passenger seat usually has wiring which detects when someone is sitting in the seat (most cars). If this is disconnected or not completely connected, the light will come on. The second is, there is usually wiring attached to the seat belts. These will deploy the pretensioners as well as tell when the belt is out. You need to check these two things, one side for the seat, both sides for the seat belts.

Comment: In addition to what Paulster2 stated I have found when the airbag light is on that cleaning the connections with either a shot of compressed air and/or electronic cleaner or silicone paste will take care of the issue.

Comment: You removed it at connectors, right?  Were any of them funny looking, have elaborate disconnect latches, and/or blue and orange? If so, there might be an air-bag *in the passenger seat*. Have you re-installed the seats and plugged everything back in, and pulled the battery for 5 minutes to reset the airbag computer? Is it still blowing errors?